Is non-template member function in class template generated only once in executable?
Example:
template<typename T>
class A {
    void f() { std::cout << "f";}
};

...

A<int> a;
A<double> a;

Is f generated once or multiple times (once for each template instantiation) in a final binary after compilation and linking? I can't seem to find this rule in the standard. AI says it's generated only once, but I don't trust it enough.

A<int> and A<double> are two different classes. So they'll have distinct member functions.

The standard isn't going to tell you what happens in the actual binary, that is an implementation detail.  I would expect each template instantiation will have its own function.

I can't seem to find this rule in the standard...." The standard doesn't deal with "executable". So you'll not find any such rule there in the standard. Search abstract machine in the standard.

@user12002570 I know they are different classes, that was not my question. AI doesn't agree with you.

@toxic "AI doesn't agree with you..." Then AI is wrong. Don't use "AI" to learn c++.  Instead use good c++ books

You can play with https://godbolt.org/z/GGeoqhP6Y and you'll see that everything is possible: two body, no body at all. Which is meaningful in your example is f does not depend on the template parameter in any way and could be, theoretically mutualized by the compiler, but, as said in other comments, it's an implementation detail, not a langage one.

You can use cppinsights

&A<int>::f  != &A<double>::f.

The standard doesn't describe the structure of a program "in a final binary after compilation and linking".
There can be any number of copies of instructions that correspond to outputting the character f to standard output. There could be 0, 1, or 2 symbols exported corresponding to those functions.
What is required is that the pointer values &A<int>::f and &A<double>::f compare unequal.

I was curious about the pointer equality, this answer worked out complications due to compiler optimizations, which of course make everything somewhat messy again.

@aasoo for a long time msvc was non-compliant in that regard


I can't seem to find this rule in the standard.

The standard doesn't deal with "executable". So you won't find anythig regarding this in the standard. Also c++ has the as-if rule.

Is f generated once or multiple times

Now, the declarations of the member functions are instantiated with the implicit instantiations of A<int> and A<double>. But the definitions are only instantiated when the member functions are actually used.
This means that since A<int> and A<double> are distinct class-types, two distinct declaration template<> void A<int>::f(); and template<> void A<double>::f() of the member functions will be instantiated. No definition of the member function will be instantiated in your program because you're not actually using the member functions.

Additional Note
You can also use cppinsights to get some insights about this.You'll note that two functions declarations are generated with cppinsights that uses clang.`

even though cppinsight shows there will be two functions, compilers typically merge identical functions into one to reduce binary size, this becomes a real pain when debugging.

@AhmedAEK Yes, compiler can use the as-if rule. As the standard doesn't deal with "executable", the question("I can't seem to find this rule in the standard") can be answered as "the standard doesn't deal with executable so you won't find any rule in the standard regarding this."
